# Create basic plugin with Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I just create new vue app with default webpack template.

`vue init webpack test`

and created a basic plugin, following is my plugin code.

```
export default {
    install(Vue, defaultOptions = {}) {

        Vue.mixin({
            mounted(){
                console.log('myplugin mixin mounted')
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When I import it in `main.js`, in the console, its print 3 times. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the out of the box webpack template your console.log will print once for the instantiated Vue, once for the App.vue, and then once for the Hello component.

This is because you have defined a global mixin with a mounted handler, which will execute for each Vue and component that is mounted.